# UTF-8 charset outputs invalid encoding in Windows Hotspot JVM 1.8.0_201

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I may be missing something basic here.

I'm just trying to encode a String using UTF-8. Following best practices, I don't assume that the default charset is UTF-8, and so I use:

```
"Ñ".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

According to the [official Unicode spec](https://unicode-table.com/en/00D1/), this should come out as: `0xc391`

However, what I'm getting instead is: `0xc383e28098`.

I'm failing to make any sense of this. This happens whether I set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` or not.

Strangely enough, when I *don't* specify the charset (or use `Charset.defaultCharset()`), the `windows-1252` encoding is used, and the output is correctly encoded UTF-8!

What's more, when I run the code through IntelliJ and not the command line, the UTF-8 charset actually does work as expected. IntelliJ adds a lot of unrelated libraries to the classpath, so I guess one of them is responsible for the correction, but I want it to work in production.

My `java -version`:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode
```

Comment: What do you exactly do to come from the `byte[]` Array to the `0xc383e28098` hex value (further Java code, file, hex editor, ...)? How long is the byte array in Java?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Why should it matter? I use a string literal and shouldn't have to care what encoding Java uses internally, it should encode the codepoints correctly. I also tried to type in the String literal as UTF-8 byte array, decode and re-encode it, and get the exact same result. 
I'll try javac anyway, but I don't see why it should help...

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I just save the bytes to a file and open it with a hex editor, using `java.nio.file.Files.write(Path, byte[])`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Actually, `"Ñ"` would be written as `"\u00d1"`.  (`"\uc391"` is a [Hangul syllable](https://graphemica.com/%EC%8E%91).)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger `"\uc391".getBytes("UTF-8")` will not produce that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your code.  The problem is how the compiler treats your source code.

When you write `"Ñ"` in your code and save the file, what bytes are actually written to the source file?

It appears you saved the source file as a UTF-8 file (which is usually a good choice).  This means `"Ñ"` was written to the file as the UTF-8 bytes 0xC3 0x91.

If you were to compile it on any operating system other than Windows, where the system’s default encoding is UTF-8, things would build and run exactly as you expect.

But when you build on Windows, where the system’s default charset is windows-1252, those two bytes in the source file get treated differently.  The compiler interprets those two bytes using windows-1252.  Regardless of what the code looks like in your editor, the compiler sees 0xC3 0x91 and treats each byte as a [windows-1252 character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set).  In windows-1252, those bytes represent:

- 0xC3 → `Ã` ([LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c3/index.htm))
- 0x91 → `‘` ([LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm))

So the compiler compiles your string constant as `"Ã‘".

All of that translation took place at compile-time only.  In a compiled .class file, all string constants are represented in the same manner;  any information about how the source was encoded is lost.  At runtime, Java only knows that you have (apparently) compiled your string as `"Ã‘"`.

At runtime, when you decode that two-character string using UTF-8, you get the UTF-8 byte sequences for those two characters:

- `Ã` → 0xc3 0x83
- `‘` → 0xe2 0x80 0x98

The solution, as you have surmised, is to tell the compiler that your source files are in UTF-8, so it will interpret the bytes 0xc3 0x91 as `Ñ`.

Comment: This is just bonkers...
I could have sworn that I tried to work directly with byte arrays and unicode literals (\u00d1) and it didn't work...
This just complicates things more for me, because the string literal was just an example for me - I'm seeing this behavior in a production env where Strings received over the wire are serialized...